# Давайте придумаем метку для всяких полезных мелочей

Tags: обсуждение, метки, создание-метки

Есть категория вопросов про разные полезные инструменты для завсегдатая StackOverflow. Например:

- разные слабо документированные фичи
- пользовательские скрипты
- полезные запросы по SEDE
- как перепостить  комментарий в чат
- как отсортировать тревоги по степени тревожности
- и так далее.

Есть пара вариантов, затрудняюсь выбрать. Хотелось бы метку понятную и нескучную.

Comment: [meta-tag:мета-мета-метки-не-нужны]

Comment: Метку для сайта или для меты?

Comment: @Qwertiy меты, конечно

Comment: ИМХО lifehack же?

Comment: @des1roer: такой вариант есть, голосуйте :) Он, хоть и первым приходит на ум, пока что не очень популярен.

Answer (score 6):

Вариант названия: [стейковерплов](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)

> Лучшие рецепты для энтузиастов SO.

Answer (score 5):

вариант названия: [знаю-как](/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba)

(от *know-how*)

Comment: О, вот это прекрасный вариант. И простой.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант названия: [очумелые-ручки](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%87%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 3):

вариант названия: [hackerflow](/questions/tagged/hackerflow) ([хакерфлоу](/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%83), [хаковерфлоу](/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%83))

Comment: И hack-exchange. :)

Comment: Как насчет кириллицы? Хакерфлоу или хаковерфлоу

Comment: насчёт кириллицы — положительно.

Comment: Возникла ассоциация: стейковерплов. Странно, вроде не голоден. :)

Answer (score 3):

Вариант названия: [знаю-хак](/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%ba)

На основе [`знаю-как`](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1467/181472)

Answer (score 3):

Может быть, не создавать для этого отдельную метку, а просто создать вопрос, где это всё расписать?

Потом этот вопрос можно при желании просто переместить в справку.

Заодно и *мета-мета-метка* не будет создана, и все интересные возможности в одном месте!

Answer (score 2):

вариант названия: [flow-how](/questions/tagged/flow-how) ([флоу-хау](/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%83-%d1%85%d0%b0%d1%83))

(от *know-how*).

Comment: Тоже отличная идея!

Answer (score 2):

Мне почему-то в голову пришли [маленькие-хитрости](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант названия:  [лайфхак](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%84%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%ba)

Comment: сначала [meta-tag:лайфхак], а потом и [meta-tag:смузи-оверфлоу]. не-не-не )

Comment: @Nofate NOOO, только не смузи. :)

Comment: @Nofate я ж про нормальную мужскую еду предлагаю вариант.

Answer (score 1):

[прочее](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b5) и всё.

Answer (score 0):

вариант названия: [flowhack](/questions/tagged/flowhack) ([флоухак](/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%83%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%ba))

Answer (score 0):

Отмечать такие вопросы меткой [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

Поскольку метка добавляется только модераторами, придумать способ, чтобы пользователи могли предлагать вопросы к добавлению этой метки. Нужны также критерии хорошего [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)-вопроса.

На En.SO это сделано через метку [faq-proposed]. Можем и мы завести, например [рекомендовано-в-faq](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2-faq)

Answer (score 0):

вариант названия: [ловкость-рук](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba)

Answer (score -1):

вариант названия:[смогу-помогу](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83).